# Add css class to Pagination?

Tags: paginate-links

I've been using this code:

```
$current_page = get_query_var('paged');
$current_page = max( 1, $current_page );

$per_page = 12;
$offset_start = 1;
$offset = ( $current_page - 1 ) * $per_page + $offset_start;

$post_list = new WP_Query(array(
    'cat'            => -15,
    'posts_per_page' => $per_page,
    'paged'          => $current_page,
    'offset'         => $offset, // Starts with the second most recent post.
    'orderby'        => 'date',  // Makes sure the posts are sorted by date.
    'order'          => 'DESC',  // And that the most recent ones come first.
));

// Manually count the number of pages, because we used a custom OFFSET (i.e.
// other than 0), so we can't simply use $post_list->max_num_pages or even
// $post_list->found_posts without extra work/calculation.
$total_rows = max( 0, $post_list->found_posts - $offset_start );
$total_pages = ceil( $total_rows / $per_page );

if ( $post_list->have_posts() ):
    while ( $post_list->have_posts() ):
        $post_list->the_post();


        // loop output here
    endwhile;

    echo paginate_links( array(
        'total'   => $total_pages,
        'current' => $current_page,
    ) );
endif;
wp_reset_postdata();
```

This is from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49227520/how-can-i-paginate-wp-query-results-when-theres-an-offset

Would it be possible to add a css class around this line?

```
   echo paginate_links( array(
        'total'   => $total_pages,
        'current' => $current_page,
    ) );
```

So it would be something like:

```
<div class="col-lg-12">
   echo paginate_links( array(
        'total'   => $total_pages,
        'current' => $current_page,
    ) );
</div>
```

Everything I've tried has led to a Wordpress Error Page

Thanks!

Comment: You would get much better performance and avoid a class oof pagination bugs you aren't aware of by using `pre_get_posts` to modify the main query, instead of throwing it away and creating a second query ( `WP_Query` doesn't replace the main query, the main query still happens even if you don't use it )

Comment: Hi Tom, bit confused by what you mean here - could you elaborate a bit? Thank you!

Comment: WordPress makes a query to the DB for posts for the main query, and this always happens, aka what you get if you use `while ( has_posts() ) { the_post(); }`, but if you ignore that and use `new WP_Query(..)` like you've done in your question that main query still happens even though you don't use them, wasting time and resources. By doing it this way the number of queries has doubled because all the original ones were ignored. If you want to change which posts WP shows, use `pre_get_posts` to modify the main query to what you want, instead of creating a 2nd query

Comment: This is why you need hacks such as `$current_page = get_query_var('paged');` to fix the second query, because functions like `paginate_links` rely on the main query, not your second custom query, but the second query is unnecessary, just modify the main query to do what you want instead and everything will work out of the box, e.g. your `paginate_links` would become `paginate_links()`

Comment: Thanks Tom, understand it completely now! I've no expertise to try and implement it though as the original post is the only workaround I could find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do what you are trying to do - add a CSS class selector to an HTML div tag, but you are mixing HTML and PHP code incorrectly. In order to do this correctly, you need to use the PHP opening/closing tags accordingly, such as:

```
?>
<div class="col-lg-12">
<?php
   echo paginate_links( array(
        'total'   => $total_pages,
        'current' => $current_page,
    ) );
?>
</div>
<?php
```

Alternatively, you could also do it like this (no need for the PHP opening/closing tags):

```
echo '<div class="col-lg-12">';
   echo paginate_links( array(
        'total'   => $total_pages,
        'current' => $current_page,
    ) );
echo '</div>';
```